# Cocoapods:[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Storage":

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

So I have several pods in my xcode project, which were all working fine.  Then I added this 'SideMenu' pod, which told me I need to change the versions of one of my pods, so I did, and now my pods are all messed up.  I'm trying to revert to what I had, which is:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Jumper' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Jumper

  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'FirebaseUI/Storage', '~> 5.0'

end
```

When I changed my Podfile back to this, and did 'pod install', I am getting this error in my terminal:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod 
"Firebase/Storage":
In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
Firebase/Storage (= 6.27.0, ~> 6.0)

In Podfile:
Firebase/Storage

FirebaseUI/Storage (~> 5.0) was resolved to 5.2.2, which depends on
  Firebase/Storage (~> 5.0)
```

I am not sure what the problem is or how to fix it.  Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want the old FirebaseUI version, remove `Podfile.lock` before `pod install`. Or run `pod update` instead of `pod install`.

`pod install` checks the Podfile.lock to prevent accidental version downgrades.

Comment: I don't want to do an old version, I just want the new versions.  I am trying to do 'pod install' with all three, and without putting any specific version, and I am getting the error: ### Error ``` Errno::ENOENT - No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/Derek/Desktop/Xcode Projects/Jumper/Pods/BoringSSL-GRPC/src/include/openssl/BoringSSL.modulemap /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod_target_installer.rb:904:in `read'  Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Maybe try `pod deintegrate` and then `pod install`

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing the '~> 5.0' part from the  pod 'FirebaseUI/Storage', '~> 5.0'. Just keep the pod 'FirebaseUI/Storage'. I hope that should work.

Comment: when i do that I get this error in my terminal: ### Error

```
Errno::ENOENT - No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/Derek/Desktop/Xcode Projects/Jumper/Pods/BoringSSL-GRPC/src/include/openssl/BoringSSL.modulemap
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod_target_installer.rb:904:in `read'   ..... I think this started when I added the 'SideMenu' pod and it started downloading that 'BoringSSL' stuff for some  reason.  I have no idea what that is